# CMD Batch file: How to use a text file to input commands

Tags: node.js, batch-file, windows-xp, cmd

I am creating a batch file to siliently install nodejs on a Windows XP machine.

I am trying to automate the installation of node module dependencies (npm install).

I would normally issue npm install from the cmd prompt in the target installation directory.

I am struggling to automate the interaction with the command prompt from a batch file.

The following line in my batch script seems to make it possible for me to pipe a text file of commands to cmd:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=," %%i in ("c:\foo\source\npm_install.txt") do echo %%i | "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
```

The batch file is located in c:\foo\source. I need to issue 'npm install' from c:\foo\bin.

If my npm_install.txt file is such:

```
  cd /d c:\foo\bin,     
  npm install
```

The cmd prompt will perform the first command changing the directory from c:\ to c:\foo\bin.

It will then perform the second command but starting from c:\ again. The previous command to change directories doesn't persist. It seems every command in the text file will be issued from c:\ .

I next tried to issue both commands from a combined statment:

```
  cd /d c:\foo\bin && npm install
```

It seems this approach will allow me to overcome the prior path problem but I then have an issue with the space between npm and install.

The cmd prompt performs c:\foo\bin>npm and causes npm to trip on the space.

I have tried enclosing the command without success: 'npm install', "npm install", (npm install).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need this: 
`do echo %%i | "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"`. Simply put your commands in a block.

```
do (
  command
  command
  ...
)
```

With your previous statement, you start new cmd interpreter, ask it to execute a command for you and exit - that's why you loose effect of that `cd`.

If you do not specify tokens in for loop, only 1st is read. Plus, all tokens must be on same line (I'm not sure if what you show is not a byproduct of formatting) 
Use `"delims="` to read full line.

Do not mix commands with arguments if you do not have to: put only directories in your file:

> c:\foo\bin
>   c:\bar\bin

so finally it becomes (I replaced cd with pushd/popd so you'll end up in the same dir you started from):

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("c:\foo\source\npm_install.txt") do (
      pushd %%i 
      npm install
      popd 
    )
```

Edit: if `npm install` is batch itself, you will need to use call, as **ebohlman** noted

Comment: Use "tokens=*" to read a full line. "tokens=" may work, but also may have unexpected side effects. `for /?` for an explanation how to use `for`.

Comment: @wmz An interesting way to do the equivalent of "tokens=*" still. I never thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your batch-processing script is creating a new subshell to handle each line in your install file. Thus your `cd` command is executed in a subshell, changing its working directory, but then the subshell exits and you're back in the parent shell's working directory.

Can your main script simply `call` your install script (whose extension would have to be changed to ".bat")? `call` lets you run another batch file in the same shell and then continue running your original script.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** These three examples do *not* require you to put `CALL` in front of any batch files, that functionality is built-into each.

The smallest and simplest, it just executes the commands **with** their arguments:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (c:\foo\source\npm_install.txt) do (
  call %%x
)
```

To mimic a person typing the commands at the keyboard:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (c:\foo\source\npm_install.txt) do (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    :: Mimic commandline
    call set "cmd=%%cd%%"
    echo !cmd!^>%%x
  endlocal
  :: Preform command
  call %%x
  echo.
)
```

To end up in the same directory you started in, no matter where the script ends:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (c:\foo\source\npm_install.txt) do (
    :: Mimic commandline
    call set "cmd=%%cd%%"
    echo !cmd!^>%%x
  :: Preform command
  call %%x
  echo.
)
endlocal
```

Comment: To get the smallest to put you back into the original directory when finished, wrap the code between `setlocal` and `endlocal`. (`enableDelayedExpansion` is not required.)